# Visual Studio: Setting Conditional Breakpoint with known GUID value

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging

I am debugging my application and wanted to set a break point on an item with a certain GUID that I know.  Lets say the GUID is the following: C5E46A52-E125-4A92-9C6B-8A6E775CDEE0.  In Visual Studio, I create a break point and set a condition.  Which of the following has a smaller performance hit:

someGuid.Equals(Guid.Parse("C5E46A52-E125-4A92-9C6B-8A6E775CDEE0"))

OR

someGuid.ToString().Equals("C5E46A52-E125-4A92-9C6B-8A6E775CDEE0"))

My gut is that the 2nd option is better because the Parse function probably has more strict rules for validation.  I'd love to know if thats true and if my gut is accurate!

Update: I mentioned this to a friend and he ran some test cases to check the performance. In his testing the string comparison was yielding ~5x better performance.

Comment: _" I'd love to know if thats true"_ -- then test it. The only way to answer the question "how fast?" is to _measure_. Since you're the one with the question, it should be you to measure it, rather than the rest of the Stack Overflow community.

Comment: To be honest, I'm not sure why you're worrying about the performance of a conditional breakpoint.

Comment: @yourbuddypal, as your updates, you got a better solution for this question, please add it as the answer, so it would be helpful for other members. Actually two ways all are good choices.

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to

```
if (someGuid.Equals(Guid.Parse("C5E46A52-E125-4A92-9C6B-8A6E775CDEE0"))) {
  ;
}
```

and place the breakpoint on the empty statement if you're truly worried about performance. Optionally you can obviously refactor the GUID instance to a static field to avoid creating it over and over again.

For the most part, honestly, I wouldn't care. Conditional breakpoints are slow, but not *that* much, usually. I tend to use above technique when I have expressions that the debugger doesn't like, but should work fine for performance fears as well.